# Alternatives to Appium Java @IOSFindBy

Tags: java, appium-android, appium-ios, appium-java

Is there a way to find elements across both operating systems without creating two separate suites now that @IOSFindBy has been deprecated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@AndroidFindBy and @iOSXCUITFindBy

Comment: Thanks, dont know why my IDE wasnt suggesting that when I typed @iOS...